# Trying to shorten redundant Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is a working javascript code. However, it looks redundant to me. Is there any way to clean this up?

```
let text = 'Some search text';

const searchMatch = 
entry.title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()) || 
entry.description.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()) || 
entry.keywords.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase());

return searchMatch;
```

Comment: one thing you can do `text = text.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an array and a `.some` test instead:

```
const textLower = text.toLowerCase();
return ['title', 'description', 'keywords']
  .map(prop => entry[prop].toLowerCase())
  .some(s => s.includes(textLower));
```

If, by chance, `entry` contains *only* those properties, then you could use `Object.values` instead:

```
return Object.values(entry)
  .map(s => s.toLowerCase())
  .some(s => s.includes(textLower));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
const text = 'Some search text'.toLowerCase();

return [entry.title, entry.description, entry.keywords].some(s => s.toLowerCase().includes(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a one-line return statement involving an array composed of `entry.description`, `entry.keywords` and `entry.title`, and then using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to return a Boolean (`true`/`false`) value depending on whether any of the tests pass:

```
return [entry.description, entry.keywords, entry.title].some(string => string.toLowerCase().includes('Some search text'.toLowerCase());
```

Here's essentially a breakdown of each part:

```
[entry.description, entry.keywords, entry.title].some(...)
```

What this does is makes an anonymous array composed of `entry.description`, `entry.keywords`, and `entry.title` (the order does not matter) and iterates through it with the `Array.prototype.some()` method. According to the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), `.some()`:

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Essentially iterates through each element, and depending on the callback from the provided function, and provides a Boolean value (`true` if at least one element in the array passes the test, `false` if no elements pass the test).

```
string => string.toLowerCase().includes('Some search text'.toLowerCase())
```

This is the anonymous function contained within the `.some()` method, and it takes a single parameter `string`. Then it returns a Boolean value, depending on the outcome of the `.includes()` method. The `.includes()` method returns another Boolean value, depending on whether the lowercased `string` contains the lowercased `'Some search text'`. It's a mouthful, but in a nutshell, the line of code above reads:

> If `string` in lowercased form includes `'Some search text'` in lowercased form, return `true` - otherwise, return `false`.

Hopefully this helps you!